# Resize texture to fit minimum rectangle

Tags: texturing, uv

I just UV unwrapped an icosphere to the default 1024x1024 texture, and the uv map has a lot of wasted space. I want to cut this texture to the minimum rectangle containing the uv map, essentially cutting at least half of the texture.

[image: image_uv_map]

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this automatically, unless someone makes a plugin. This is how I did it with external image manipulation programs.

- This is the current UV unwrap

[image]

- To save the image from Blender, open it in the UV Editor and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to Save As. Then use an external image editor to crop the image. Note the factor you are cropping by. If you crop it down by 1/2, note down 2. 1/3 is 3, 3/4 is 1.333... etc. 
   Go back to the UV Editor, click on Image > Replace. Find and select the cropped image. It should look like this:

[image]

- Now in the UV Editor, press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the sidebar if it isn't up already. Click View, then set the 2D Cursor to 0,0.

[image]

- Select all the vertices in the UV Editor with <kbd>A</kbd>. Press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> to Scale on the Y axis. Then enter your factor I mentioned before. I cropped the image by a half so I'll enter 2. Left click to finish scale.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Benus, thanks for your input. I'm very disappointed this isn't a feature. It's not practical to do this manually with dozens of textures, and more importantly, how do I find the exact amount to crop?